# How can i fix the position of controls when scrolling in Winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, add-in

i am implementing a controlAddIn for Dynamics Nav with C#. It is a matrix control with panels. All the controls are inside a MainPanel. I have the line headers(first panel of line) and the line totals(last panel).The same for the column headers(first panel of column) and column total(last panel of column). I have got my functions to do the matrix working good, the elements inside the mainPanel are implemented in the following order, all in différents functions:

1-Column Headers.
2-Row Headers.
3-Column Total 1 + Intersection of column 1 with rows(if i have got one column and three rows, i will have three intersections(also panels)).
4-Column Total n + Intersection of column n with rows.
5-Row Totals.
6-Total of totals.

If i have got 6 columns and 6 rows it gets me a table of 7*7(with the totals). MainPanel have a fixed size and have the AutoScroll = true. So when i arrived to scroll positions the elements scroll without problems. I want to fix the position of the headers and the totals when i scroll horizontal or vertical.

Which is the best way to achieve this? I am doing it defining some area where the panels will be invisible. (panel.visible = false). Is this a good way of doing it? I thought of doing drawing some kinds of area to hide the panels that could be in this areas on scrolling.

Thanks, i put some code for more info.

```
if (nRolesG > 5)
        {
            MainPanel.SetAutoScrollMargin(140, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            MainPanel.SetAutoScrollMargin(0, 0);
        }
        if (nOperationsG > 7)
        {
            pnRole.Location = new Point(pnRole.Left, 0);

            MainPanel.MouseWheel += (senderL, eL) =>
            {
                pnRole.Location = new Point(pnRole.Left, 0);
            };
            MainPanel.Scroll += (senderL, eL) =>
            {
                pnRole.Location = new Point(pnRole.Left, 0);
            };
        }
        MainPanel.MouseWheel += (senderL, eL) =>
        {
            pnRole.Left = (posRoleL * 140) + 80;
            pnRole.Top = 0;

            if ((pnRole.Location.X < 220) || (pnRole.Location.X > 1130))
            {
                pnRole.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                pnRole.Visible = true;
            }

        };
        MainPanel.Scroll += (senderL, eL) =>
        {
            pnRole.Left = (posRoleL * 140) + 80;
            pnRole.Top = 0;

            if ((pnRole.Location.X < 220) || (pnRole.Location.X > 1130))
            {
                pnRole.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                pnRole.Visible = true;
            }
        };
```

This is the code for the colum headers, but the rest of the functions are similar.

Thanks again to any help.

Comment: Just use another panel that you put between the header and footer.  Make *that* one scrollable.

Comment: Hello @HansPassant, I thought of doing like this but i want to do scroll vertical and horizontal. And i thought that putting two panels maybe was going to cause some sort of problem.